# Flutter page closes when I tap on the text field

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[FINAL UPDATE - Problem Solved]

A dear friend of mine, [Abhijith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6609599/abhijith-konnayil) took a look at the code following the inputs from [Suat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14269222/suat-%c3%96zkaya) and noted that I have been using a UniqueKey() constructor in my main function.

[image]

This made it so that each time there was a State change and the build method was called, the key associated with the basic app kept changing, which caused the whole app to rebuild from the home screen.

Simply removing the key parameter, or saving the UniqueKey() in a key variable as shown below, before passing it into the key parameter will also do the trick.

[image]

That being said, I'm marking this thread as closed and I thank everyone for all your time and effort . Cheers!

[Original Post]

I have been working on a Flutter project for my college work. In my project there is a create project page, where the user is supposed to enter some details including the project name to proceed with the creation. But whenever I try to enter some text using a TextField, the application takes me back to the home screen. Please see the following demonstration for reference

[Demonstration](https://youtube.com/shorts/4aLTMQ1WnwM)

```
Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 24 / 360 * ScreenConstants.screenWidth,
                  top: 25 / 360 * ScreenConstants.screenWidth,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "Project Name",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _projectNameFocusNode.requestFocus();
                },
                child: TextFormField(
                  focusNode: _projectNameFocusNode,
                  controller: _projectNameController,
                  // Rest of your TextFormField configuration
                ),
              )
            ],
```

This is the code in question. I have tried using InkWell as above, GestureDetector, and TextField by itself. But whatever I do, the error keeps repeating itself.

Can you guys help me figure out what's going on here? Thanks a lot!

[Edit 1]
This is the logs I get as the control flows outside the page

```
I/ImeTracker( 9719): com.example.kaptur_alpha_v1:31b874ef: onRequestShow at ORIGIN_CLIENT_SHOW_SOFT_INPUT reason SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InputMethodManager( 9719): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{a6c6e42 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2154 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 9719): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/EGL_emulation( 9719): app_time_stats: avg=42.17ms min=29.73ms max=57.70ms count=24
D/EGL_emulation( 9719): app_time_stats: avg=468.49ms min=1.20ms max=13982.47ms count=30
```

[Edit 2]

Including the screenshots of the widget tree during different states.

[image: Widget Tree in Home Screen]

[image: Widget Tree in New Project Page]

[image: Widget Tree after clicking on text field]

[Edit 3]

Suat's observation was spot on. The app rebuilds itself for some reason after the text field is clicked. A print statement included in the main method confirms that the app is indeed rebuilding and not restarting.

This image shows the testing code included and the corresponding output. I believe the output suggests that the application rebuilds itself four times.
[image]

Comment: Hard to see what's wrong here. But I would guess somewhere `Navigator.pop` is called. My approach would be to do a project wide search on `Navigator.pop` to see all locations where it's called, and try to see if it's triggered somewhere, possibly by putting a different `print` before each place where `pop` is called and then work from there

Comment: Hey there. I tried adding a print statement to every pop instance in my code and none of them are executed as the control flows out. I have also tried doing the sam outside an emulator and got the same result.

Comment: Your change notifiers id number is changed. I think the page is not popping but your whole app re-starts, reloads. Firstly check if this is true, by adding some prints to the main and build methods. Then look for listeners and how you implement the provider package.

Comment: @SuatÖzkaya you're right. The app does rebuild itself. Let me see if I can figure out what is going on underneath. In the meantime, do you have anything that I should be specifically looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `UniqueKey()` in `ChangeNotifierProvider`. It will lead to the rebuilding of the Widget.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue then I checked Flutter Inspector and saw that I was accidentally pushing the previous page over and over again, which makes you think that the current page is popping. I suggest you to check your navigation stack for a similar bug.
I am adding a sample screenshot below. Here MyHomePage is accidentally being pushed many times.

[image]

Comment: Hello Suat, thank you for your answer. I tried checking the Flutter Inspector but I couldn't find the navigation stack you mentioned. I tried checking the logs but I couldn't find anything mentioning the previous page being pushed. Could you share more details about how to check the navigation stack?

Comment: @kris, I added a screen shot in the answer. I Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey there. I have edited the question to add screenshots including the widget tree at different states. As you can see, the home screen is actually not being pushed. Either the second screen is being popped, or something is causing it to close by itself. I can't figure out what is the issue here. Any input is appreciated.